# Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lr\lr.php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to sanitize all the data of array `$register_data` . For that I am using `array_walk()` in which I am passing the second parameter as the sanitize function, but I am getting this warning :

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp..

Below is my code:

```
function register_user($register_data) {
    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
    $register_data['password'] = md5($register_data['password']);
    print_r($register_data);
}

function array_sanitize($conn, &$item) {
    $item = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $item);
}

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if(!$conn) {
    die();
}
```

Comment: MD5 is not appropriate for hashing passwords. Please, follow [password hashing](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing) best practices. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and stay away from these "sanitize" functions. Even better, use a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that comes with an 
[authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication) built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_sanitize` requires 2 arguments, and the second one should be the item. The arguments `array_walk()` passes to the function are the array element and its index.

The simplest fix is to change `array_sanitize` to take just one argument, and get `$conn` from the global variable:

```
function array_sanitize(&$item) {
    global $conn;
    $item = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $item);
}
```